# Paralelismo no Sql Server com C#

Tags: sql-server, async, assincronismo, paralelismo

Estou implementando métodos async no C# e gostaria de saber como proceder quando chego no Sql.

Quando abro uma conexão com o sql server, ele me permite o paralelismo através de apenas uma conexão? Ou seja, posso enviar varias queries pra ele que ele executara em paralelo?

Se sim, qual o máximo de queries paralelas ele consegue fazer em paralelo?

Caso não, preciso de varias conexões diferentes pra que ele entenda que pode fazer tudo ao mesmo tempo?

pra qualquer uma das respostas preciso configurar alguma coisa no sql ou nas queries(sejam elas SP ou commands)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fernando, O Sql Server aceita que várias consultas sejam feitas por uma única conexão. A maior questão aqui é: qual operação você irá realizar em paralelo? Quando há concorrência no banco de dados(múltiplos acessos simultâneos) podem ocorrer locks/bloqueios além de *Deadlocks*. Se forem operações de leitura, veja se há necessidade de realizar leituras limpas (ou seja, com a posição mais recente do banco, aguardando que não haja bloqueio nas tabelas para realizar a leitura), se não houver essa necessidade, utilize **(nolock)** no **from** e seja feliz. Agora, caso sejam operações de **inclusão, alteração e delete**, podem haver muitos locks e deadlocks e o seu banco irá travar. Neste caso, você pode represar as alterações durante o processamento paralelo no lado da aplicação e aplicar as mudanças no banco em lote.

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com este link (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/asynchronous-programming), se a sua versão .Net menor que 4.5, então é necessário informar `Asynchronous Processing=true` no seu objeto connection. Do contrário o SqlDataReader possui métodos async para read/write.

> Quando abro uma conexão com o sql server, ele me permite o paralelismo através de apenas uma conexão? Ou seja, posso enviar varias queries pra ele que ele executara em paralelo?

Sim

> Se sim, qual o máximo de queries paralelas ele consegue fazer em paralelo?

Não tenho um número exato, mas provavelmente o limite de queries simultâneas que o sql server suporta

> pra qualquer uma das respostas preciso configurar alguma coisa no sql ou nas queries(sejam elas SP ou commands)?

Pelo que entendo quem vai aguardar a resposta assíncrona seria a sua aplicação C#, e não o SQL Server propriamente, então quem deve fazer a consulta async é o client e a sua SP/Trigger deve ser escrita de forma padrão.

Existem outras considerações que não vou abordar profundamente aqui, pois não foi o foco da sua questão, como polling e events, que são as maneiras de aguardar que uma query seja executada. Neste caso específico suponho que seja event por `callback` e `await`.

Exemplo (Se a versão .Net < 4.5):

```
static void Terminou(IAsyncResult result) {
// callback que será invocado
}

void main() {
    // Código principal
    IAsyncResult result = command.BeginExecuteReader(new AsyncCallback(Terminou));
}
```

Exemplo (Versão > 4.5):

```
SqlDataReader reader;
await reader.ReadAsync(); // aguarda retorno assíncrono
```